# laravel 5.2 How to get route parameter in blade?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

this is my url
`http://project.dev/blogs/image-with-article`
so, here I need the parameter `image-with-article`
in my blade to display which is a parameter named slug here is in my routes file I need the slug paramter in blade.

```
Route::get('/blogs/{slug}', ['as'=>'blog.by.slug', 'uses'=> 'CmsController@show']);
```

Answer (score 85, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean. If you're trying to construct the route in a Blade template, use

```
<a href="{{ route('blog.by.slug', ['slug' => 'someslug']) }}">...</a>
```

If you're trying to access the given parameter, I would suggest passing it from the controller:

```
// CmsController
public function show($slug)
{
    // other stuff here
    return view('someview', compact('slug'));
}

// someview.blade.php
{{ $slug }}
```

And if you really need to access the parameter from the view without first sending it from the controller... you really shouldn't, but you can use the facade:

```
{{ Request::route('slug') }}
```

Comment: I would like to give myself a shoutout for searching for how to do this only to find my two year younger self telling me it's a stupid idea.

Comment: Hi, why would your last solution be a bad practice? I see it as a good shortcut in the template to not unnecessary occupy the array of variables passed to it.

Comment: @ankabot I generally want to keep any logic outside of views and just pass them anything they need. It's not a strict rule and it's up to everyone what they prefer, but it's generally considered a best practice.

Comment: @JoelHinz I wouldn't call `Request::route()` logic - it seems pretty standard for Laravel.

Answer (score 37):

If you want to get the parameters without using the controller method

```
{{dd(request()->route()->parameters)}}
```

Comment: This doesn't work; it returns empty. `dd(request()->query('testing'))` works though.

Answer (score 13):

In Laravel 8, you can simply use `request()->route('parameter_name')`.

Answer (score 7):

Easy way Just
`{{ dd(request()->query("PARAMNAME")) }}`

for get all PARAMs
`{{ dd(request()->query()) }}`