# How to print values passed by get method in next view in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5.3

I have passed parameter for my get route by

```
 <a href="{{ route('product.list', $product->category) }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Show more</a>
```

And my route is

```
Route::get('list/{category}', ['as' => 'tour.featured', 'uses' => 'PublicController@productList']);
```

I want to display the category name in my product-list.blade.php view
This is what i have tried:

```
{{$_GET['category']}}
```

This is giving me error of

```
Undefined index: category
```

Comment: post your controller code

Comment: share `productList` method from `PublicController` controller ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `{{request()->route('category')}}`

Answer (score 1):

Use your same route and make your controller like:

```
public function yourMethod($category)
{
    // other stuff here, will return value for $category
    return view('someview', COMPACT('category'));
}
```

And now you can use $category value into your blade file like:

```
{{ $category }}
```

Answer reference: [laravel 5.2 How to get route parameter in blade?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39011648/laravel-5-2-how-to-get-route-parameter-in-blade)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing one step:

```
Route::get('list/{category}', ['as' => 'tour.featured', 'uses' => 'PublicController@productList']);
```

after that, you have to create the **productList** method in PublicController like

```
function PublicController(Request $request)
{
    echo $request;   // will print the data in $product->category
    // Now you can pass this value to your view like:
    return view('view_name', array('category', $product->category));
}
```

and get this on view like:

```
{{$_GET['category']}}
```

Comment: `echo $request;` will goes to infinite loop. Use `echo $request->all();` instad.